# How to get a list of methods of an object or class?

Tags: java

I need to find a list of the methods and public properties that are in an object dynamically. I will not have access to the class's definition. Is it possible to get a list of methods of an object given a reference to the object? If so, how?

Comment: Recursive answer: use reflexion on someObject.getClass() to see how you can use relfexion `;o)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the class by calling `getClass()` on the reference. From there, you can call getMethods(), getDeclaredMethods() etc. Sample code showing the methods in `java.lang.String`:

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showMethods("hello");
    }

    private static void showMethods(Object target) {
        Class<?> clazz = target.getClass();

        for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the docs for [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more options of how to get methods etc.

Answer (score 2):

java reflection api can do this for you.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html

Answer (score 1):

look here for a good introduction in java reflection:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

With reflection you can get every method and object for a given class (next to many more features)